# Is $k-$secant lines independent of embedding?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is the number of $k-$secant lines to a surface $S$ depends on the embedding of $S$ ? More precisely suppose $S \to \mathbb{P}^N$ be a surface in $\mathbb{P}^N$, then it is known that $S$ can be projected isomorphically to $\mathbb{P}^5$.

Question:  Is the number of $k-$secant lines to $S$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$ equals to the number of $k-$ secant lines to $S$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ ?

Comment: It is rather exceptional that a surface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ has a finite number of $k$-secants. This occurs for $n=4, k=6$; $n=5,k=4$; $n=7, k=3$, plus a number of particular surfaces.

Comment: Do you mean that if $n \ge 5$ and $5 \le k \le \text{deg}(S)$ then the $k-$secant lines has positive dimension ?

Comment: The expected dimension of the variety of $k$-secants is $2n-2-k(n-3)$, and this is indeed the actual dimension for most surfaces. It is an easy exercise to prove that this number is 0 only in the 3 cases I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I am still a bit confused.  Here,  by a $k-$secant line, I meant a line intersecting the surface at $k$ points. Probably your definition of $k-$secant is different from mine.

Comment: No, this is what I meant — what else?

Comment: If that is the case, then for $n= 4$ and $k=8$ there is no surface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ with $8-$secant line. On the other hand, if we choose $8$ points in a line in $\mathbb{P}^4$, then we can find two  hypersurfaces of higher degree passing through those $8$ points. Now   their intersection is a surface.  Thus we can find many surfaces with $8-$ secant lines. Please let me know if i am doing any mistake.

Comment: Where did I say that  there is no surface in $\Bbb{P}^4$ with 8−secant line? I mentioned the *expected* dimension, there are of course exceptions.

Comment: Ok. I understood.